# Example of convex functions fulfilling a (strange) lower bound

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, examples, calculus-of-variations

I am reading a preliminary version of a paper which focuses on some minimization problems connected to a class of integral functionals. Reading the assumptions of one of the theorems I cannot convince myself that a "concrete" example exists (beside the "trivial" function, $x \mapsto \alpha \vert x \vert$ for some $\alpha >0$: the authors want to extend some previous result on this case to a more general framework).

**Question.** Does there exist a function $f \colon \mathbb R^N \to [0,+\infty)$ such that

1. $f$ is convex;
2. $f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x)$ for any $\lambda >0$ and $\forall x \in \mathbb R^N$;
3. there are $a>0, b \ge 0$ and $\gamma \in \mathbb R^N$ such that 
   $$
   a|x| \le f(x) + \langle \gamma, x \rangle + b
   $$
   for any $x \in \mathbb R^N$?

I have some problems in finding a function satisfying the three points... It does not have to be smooth, still I do not see an example beside $\alpha |x|$, $\alpha >0$.

Comment: Does $f(x) = |x|$ not work?

Comment: @πr8 Sure, I forgot to mention that I am looking for another function than the norm :-) You are perfectly right, thanks!

Comment: Then take $k|x|$, $k>0$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I see your point and thanks for the comment, yet I am looking for a completely "different" example. I have not written it in the OP (to avoid being too long and verbose) but this function $f$ plays the role of integrand of a min problem in CoV, i.e. $\min \int_\Omega f(Du) dx$ among suitable competitors $u$. I am not interested into the case $f(\cdot) = \vert \cdot \vert$ (which is well-known) and, as you can now see, multiplicative constants do not play any role.

Comment: The form of (3) suggests $a|x| - \langle \gamma, x\rangle$ as a possibility. Doesn't that work (for small enough $|\gamma|$)?

Comment: @YoavKallus That is also good try, thanks. The point in choosing small $|\gamma|$ is to ensure non negativity, right? This seems an interesting example disjoint from the class indicated by iosif Pinelis. Thanks you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G$ be the set of functions $g\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that for some strictly positive real $a$ and $b$ and all real $x$ we have $g(x)=-ax$ if $x\le0$ and $g(x)=bx$ if $x\ge0$. Let $l_1,\dots,l_N$ be any linearly independent linear functionals on $\mathbb R^N$. Then any function $f$ on $\mathbb R^N$ of the form 
\begin{equation*}
 f=\sum_1^N g_i\circ l_i
\end{equation*}
with the $g_i$'s in $G$ will be nonnegative and satisfy your conditions 1, 2, 3. 
More generally, we can take 
\begin{equation*}
 f=\sum_1^n g_i\circ l_i \tag{0}
\end{equation*}
with the $g_i$'s in $G$, where $l_1,\dots,l_n$ are any linear functionals on $\mathbb R^N$ spanning $(\mathbb R^N)^*$.

**Added in response to a comment by the OP:** Here are details on why the so-constructed $f$ will satisfy condition 3. Let 
\begin{equation}
 c:=\inf_{x\ne0}\frac{f(x)}{|x|}=\min_{|x|=1}f(x),  \tag{1}
\end{equation}
since $f$ is positive homogeneous and continuous. 
Suppose that $f(x)=0$ for some $x\in\mathbb R^N$. Since $g_i\ge0$, (0) implies $g_i(l_i(x))=0$ for all $i$. Since $g_i(u)=0\implies u=0$, we have $l_i(x)=0$ for all $i$, and hence $l(x)=0$ for all $l\in(\mathbb R^N)^*$, since the $l_i$'s span $(\mathbb R^N)^*$. So, $f(x)=0$ implies $x=0$. So, (1) implies $c>0$ and $c|x|\le f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^N$, so that condition 3 indeed holds.

Comment: Marvellous idea, thanks a lot! I have checked without problems the (non-strict) convexity and the positive homogeneity of degree 1. I fail to see why they also satisfy point (3), would you mind expanding a bit your answer about this point? Thank you very much for your interest and for your answer!

Comment: @Y.B. : I have added details on condition 3.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details. Your post has been very helpful, as usual.

Answer (score 3):

Another construction that works is the following: Take any convex $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ which contains a neighborhood of the origin. Then the associated *Minkowski functional*
$$
\sigma_A(x) = \inf\{\lambda>0\mid x\in\lambda A\}
$$
has the desired properties.

Comment: Nice idea, too! I had almost forgotten my old Functional Analysis class :-) Is it possibile to characterize the sets $A$ for which $\sigma_A$ is a strictly convex function?Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, that's simple: $\sigma_A$ is never strictly convex (as it is positively homogeneous).

Comment: That's right, thank you very much!

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again, but I now fail to see why $\sigma_A$ fulfills Property (3). Maybe we need that $A$ is open? I believe in this case probably one can choose $\gamma=0$ and also $b=0$, but I am not sure. Thanks.

Comment: You need that $A$ contains an open neighborhood of the origin, i.e. a ball $B_\epsilon(0)$. Then $|x|=1$ implies that $\epsilon x\in A$, i.e. $x\in \epsilon^{-1}A$, i.e. $\sigma_A(x)\geq \epsilon^{-1}$. By positive homogeneity this shows that indeed $\gamma=0$, $\beta=0$ and $a = \epsilon^{-1}$ work.

Comment: Yes, I got it now, thanks (I made a mistake in my proof and it seemed to me we needed $A$ to be open). Your argument is definitively more clear and transparent. Thanks a lot!